# Should a vegan be concerned about choline intake?

Tags: veganism, nutrition, supplements, lacto-vegetarianism, nutritional-deficiency

Choline is an essential nutrient for human health and may be hard to get for both vegans and vegetarians. The daily Adequate Intake (AI) for choline is 550 mg for men and 425-450 mg for women (up to 550 for breastfeeding women), and many people (including non-vegetarians) seem to be deficient in choline, despite its [beneficial properties](https://veganhealth.org/choline/). An egg provides about [25% of the AI](https://www.healthline.com/nutrition/foods-with-choline), while plant sources may provide sufficient choline if chosen carefully. Also, [veganhealth.com](https://veganhealth.org/choline/) suggests pregnant woman could take a choline supplement, and that there are no studies on choline status of vegans, which may seem concerning. The [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Choline) page on Choline links to a number of health problems associated with choline deficiency.

Do you reckon vegans (or even lacto-vegetarians) should be concerned for adequate choline intake and seek supplementation?